# Extracting data shown in Version Changes on Branch-Versioned feature service before reconcile/post process using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning, feature-service

Currently there is no way to export version changes on feature service in ArcGIS Pro as a change report. Preferably a Python script to extract the details about version changes on a branch-versioned feature service before the reconcile/post process.

Is this possible or has anyone implemented this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the ArcGIS API for Python. First you need to generate a GIS object and a VersionManager object.

The URL to your Version Management Server will be the same format as the URL of your feature server with ‘VersionManagementServer’ at the end.

Then you can either list all versions as I have done below or call a specific version by name or GlobalID.

You must first start_reading on a version, generate a dictionary of changes, and then stop_reading.

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.features import _version

my_gis = GIS(URL, Username, Password) #many options depending on authentication type
my_vms = r'https://gis.EXAMPLE.com/un/rest/services/EXAMPLE/EXAMPLE/VersionManagementServer'
VersionManager = _version.VersionManager(my_vms, my_gis)
VersionList = VersionManager.all

for Version in VersionList:
    if not Version.properties["isLocked"]:
        Version.start_reading()
        Differences = Version.differences(result_type='objectIds', moment=None) 
        Version.stop_reading()
        if 'differences' in Differences:
            print(Differences)
        else:
            print('No changes: '+ str(Version))
```